# How to Design own theme on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to design my own theme on Wordpress but I have basic knowledge of PHP. Can I do it? I have good knowledge of WordPress. I customize many themes in WordPress but this time I want my own theme.

Comment: You can do it. There are many resources available to you online.

Comment: The answer lies within your question itself "I have good knowledge of WordPress".

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you have "good knowledge of Wordpress" you should also know the official theme development documentation by Wordpress itself. It's a good starting point.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

You can start with https://underscores.me/. It's a configurable starter theme produce by Automattic (the distributor of WordPress). You can find many informations and details on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. If you get a URL and obviously set a database up for it, [download WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) and set up your file structure. I recommend using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) as this makes it 100x easier to incorporate content from the WP backend, to show on the front end.

You can also find many plugins on [GitHub](https://github.com) to help you such as this [Slider function](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider) that I use a lot on my own wp themes.

You can also view pre-set WordPress PHP functions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/) which you can use in your site easily without having to know too much PHP.